# IBM Worklight request timeout

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I made an app that connect to server to get some info

I use HTTPAdapter to send a post request

It runs successfully with preview on my browser

I've check that tha adapter and code has no bug

but it failed when I run it on my virtual device(3G network)

```
Request timeout for [http://172.16.100.106:10080/WistronAppProject/apps/services/api/WistronApp/android/query]
```

why i can't send request with different ip domain ?

it has to run in the same network?

there is some other problem?

Answer (score 2):

The device must be able to connect to the same network Worklight Server is in.

If your server does not have a PUBLIC IP address, meaning it is running for example in your office network that is not available outside, then your device MUST be connected to the same office network via WiFi. If you connect via 3G, it will not be able to find the Worklight Server and connect to it.

Comment: @IdanAdar When client tries to connect to server via 3g the busy indicator doesnt fire..is there a way to show a busy indicator while the client tries to connect?

Comment: Read about wl.busyindicator and use it where you see fit